# How can I determine the size of variable in memory WITHOUT creating it?

Tags: matlab, memory, size

Is that possible? Let's say I wanted to determine how many bytes a variable **WILL** occupy given I know the dimension, so that an appropriate procedure can be taken before doing the computation. The classic way:

```
A = zeros(500, 500, 500);
whos A;
```

You might suggest to just delete the variable after the `whos` command, but if MATLAB has almost reached the max memory capacity, this might not work. Is there an elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For matrices of standard [numeric types](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/numeric-types.html) all you need to know is the number of elements in your matrix and the number of bytes in the data type. For your example, your matrix will be of type `double` by default, which is 8 bytes, so your total matrix size will be:

```
matrixSize = [500 500 500];
byteSize = prod(matrixSize)*8;
```

You can figure out the byte size for a given data type from a scalar variable of that type using [`whos`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/whos.html):

```
temp = uint8(0);           % Sample uint8 variable
varData = whos('temp');    % Get variable data from whos
varBytes = varData.bytes;  % Get number of bytes

varBytes =

     1                     % uint8 takes 1 byte
```

[As mentioned by Sam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43850676/determine-the-size-of-variable-in-memory-without-creating-the-variable-in-matlab#comment74741902_43850775), container classes like [cell arrays](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html) and [structures](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/structures.html) make it a little bit more complicated to compute the total byte usage since they require some memory overhead.

Comment: Also: the memory taken for cell arrays is the memory for the cell contents plus an overhead of 112 bytes per cell, and the memory taken for structs is the memory for the field contents plus an overhead of 224 bytes per field.

Comment: Thanks both of you! That's a nice way to do it.